# Autoclose GNU Readline

Tags: libreadline

Working on various GNU Readline-based CLIs and it would dramatically
speed me up if there was a way to have brackets and quotes
automatically closed when you type.

Thus typing a `'` or `(` on Bash (or other CLIs) would actually
append the closing quote or bracket `''` or `()` and place the cursor
inbetween for writing.

I've looked around for quite some time trying to find out anything related
(e.g. `~/.inputrc` setting), but didn't find anything and I wonder if that's
at all achievable. Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but doable. As a `bash` command:

```
bind '"(" "\C-v()\e[D"'
bind '"\"" "\C-v\"\C-v\"\e[D"'
```

As a setting in `.inputrc` (so any program using `readline` gets the behavior):

```
"(": "\C-v()\e[D"
"\"": "\C-v\"\C-v\"\e[D"
```

You can prefix each key with Control-v to type "plain" quotes and left parentheses without triggering the auto-close behavior.

The above assumes Emacs keybindings. For vi bindings, use

```
bind '"(": "\C-v()\ei"'
bind '"\"" "\C-v\"\C-v\"\ei"'
```

or

```
"(": "\C-v()\ei"
 "\"": "\C-v\"\C-v\"\ei"
```

Essentially, just replace the `[D` with `i`; instead of sending the escape sequence to move the cursor left, just send `\e` to drop back into command mode after inserting the parentheses/quotes, then re-enter insert mode, which should position the cursor inside the characters just typed.

Comment: This is all nice, but if I have `set editing-mode vi`, it puts me out of insert mode after autocompletion, which is quite annoying. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Doing exactly what you want is impossible, but there is a work around.
Put this in inputrc:

```
"\C-x\"": "\"\"C-b"
```

Run:

```
info readline "comm" "readline init" "sample"
```

for the whole sample.

Comment: Not impossible, just convoluted.