# ipython notebook: how to toggle header invisible by default

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to save some space for my 14 inch screen.  What should I write in e.g. ipython_notebook_config.py to trigger this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. If it doesn't already exist, create a file named `custom.js` in `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/`
   (You may have to run `ipython profile create`, if you have never run this command.)
2. In `custom.js`, put the following lines of JavaScript

   ```
   $([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
       $('div#header').hide();
   });
   ```
3. If you would like to also hide the toolbar by default, use these lines of JavaScript instead

   ```
   $([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
       $('div#header').hide();
       $('div#maintoolbar').hide();
   });
   ```

Comment: For Ipython3 use "$('div#header-container').hide();" instead of "$('div#header').hide();"

Comment: You can also add a [keyboard shortcut to toggle the header, menu and toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876235/ipython-notebook-3-hide-headers-by-default?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a recent IPython, like v3.0.0 or higher, and are seeing only sporadic success with this method, you'll need to hook into the RequireJS dependency loader, and put the following in your `common.js`:

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
  $('#header-container').hide();
});
```

`common.js` is loaded at the bottom of the page, so there's no need to wait for the DOM ready event, i.e., `$(function() { ... })`.

For further discussion see my answer at [Turn off auto-closing parentheses in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29702505/424651) and its comments.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `Anaconda3`, please do:

1. update your `C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom\custom.css`

   > ```
   > .container{ width:100% !important; }
   > div#site{ height: 100% !important; }
   > ```
2. update your `C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom\custom.js`, and we add a shortcut `ctrl+` for toggle the header

   ```
   $([IPython.events]).on('notebook_loaded.Notebook',function(){
       $('#header').hide();
       IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-`',function (event) {
           if (IPython.notebook.mode == 'command') {
               $('#header').toggle();
               return false;
           }
           return true;
       });
   });
   ```