# IPython/Jupyter notebook 3 - hide headers by default

Tags: ipython, customization, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Before IPython notebook version 3.0 the notebook headers could be hidden by default by adding this to ".ipython\profile_default\static\custom\custom.js" (on Windows):

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
    $('div#header').hide();
    $('div#maintoolbar').hide();
});
```

or for Jupyter, "~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js", with `IPython` replaced by `Jupyter`.

[also see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540870/ipython-notebook-how-to-toggle-header-invisible-by-default)

This does not seem to work anymore. It hides the headers, but it also leaves a big gap on the page's top and bottom.
I am not familiar with javascript and css. Has anyone found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add this to custom.css in your profile (e.g. ~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.css for me):

```
div#site{
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

to remove any nasty grey space at the bottom. Also, I add this to my custom.js (same folder) to toggle the header using ctrl-`  :

```
$([IPython.events]).on('notebook_loaded.Notebook', function(){
    $('#header').hide();

    IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-`', function (event) {
        if (IPython.notebook.mode == 'command') {
            $('#header').toggle();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

The downside is that you can accidentally scroll the header partially off the page, but that only happens if you scroll on it and it's not a big deal, especially if you want it hidden mostly anyway.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Just a note: This hides the header completely. The solution I used before left the row with the menu intact. So you really have to use the ctrl+` shortcut now. However, I even like it better that way.

Comment: In addition to utilizing the full height, you can also [remove the gray space on the sides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser), by adding `.container { width:100% !important; }` to `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.css`.

Comment: Another note, if you are using Jupyter notebook by chance, you'll need to `jupyter migrate` so that same js and css files work in jupyter - http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html

Comment: You might also need to restart the notebook server for the css changes to take effect.

Comment: This should be an extension

Answer (score 5):

In ipython 3, `#header` refers to the complete assembly at the top of the page, not just the image banner as it did in ipython 2.

To permanently hide the toolbar and header **while keeping the menu**, I added

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
    $('div#header-container').hide();
    $('div#maintoolbar').hide();
});
```

to my `~/.ipython/profile_name/static/custom/custom.js`

Answer (score 2):

Combining the answers by @John_C and @cknd and avoiding the `-key (which is a dead-key on my (Dutch) keyboard layout), I added this to my `~/.ipython/profile_name/static/custom/custom.js`:

```
$([IPython.events]).on('notebook_loaded.Notebook', function(){
    $('#header').hide();
    IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-;', function (event) {
        if (IPython.notebook.mode == 'command') {
            $('#header').toggle();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

    IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-.', function (event) {
        if (IPython.notebook.mode == 'command') {
            $('#header').show();
            $('#header-container').toggle();
            $('#maintoolbar').toggle();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to update this work for jupyter 4/5 using a small raspberry pi LCD.

As of jupyter 4.x, the script is now needed in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`

I used this function which doesn't just hide the tabs normally, but also moves the persistent bar into the scrollable region. Did I mention this is on a tiny LCD? We need every pixel!

```js
define(['base/js/events'], function(events) {
  events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function () {
    $('#header-container').toggle();
    $('.header-bar').toggle();
    $('div#maintoolbar').toggle();
    $('#site').prepend($("#header").detach());
    events.trigger('resize-header.Page');
  });
});
```

It was also necessary to eliminate the bottom border using `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`

```
div#notebook{
  padding: 0;
}
div#site{
  height: 100% !important;
}
```