# How to disable auto-quotes and auto-brackets in Jupyter 5.0

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I upgraded Jupyter to the latest vesion, 5.0, and it looks like my front-end configuration stopped working.

I don't understand why Jupyter comes with auto closing quotes and brackets by default, which I find pretty annoying. So, at each version I have to change the settings to disable it.

It used to work by creating a file `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` and adding the next JavaScript code:

```
require(['notebook/js/codecell'], function (codecell) {
  codecell.CodeCell.options_default.cm_config.autoCloseBrackets = false;
})
```

I've read that since Jupyter 4 this code could be changed by:

```
IPython.CodeCell.options_default.cm_config.autoCloseBrackets = false;
```

But it looks like in Jupyter 5, the two previous options stopped working.

The documentation I found regarding the front-end configuration is not helpful (I'll be happy to improve it once I understand it):

http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frontend_config.html#frontend-config

Can anyone help me understand how to disable auto-brackets and auto-quotes in Jupyter 5 please?

This is the exact version I'm running:

[image]

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It looks like it can be done by running in a notebook:

```
from notebook.services.config import ConfigManager
c = ConfigManager()
c.update('notebook', {"CodeCell": {"cm_config": {"autoCloseBrackets": False}}})
```

This creates a file `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json` with the content:

```
{
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "autoCloseBrackets": false
    }
  }
}
```

After executing the Python command, or manually creating the file, restart your Jupyter notebook, and it should stop auto-closing quotes and brackets.

Comment: Since you found the answer and shared it here (and many are finding it useful) please go ahead and mark it as accepted. Thanks.'

Comment: If you're using JupyterLabs, the instructions are different: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3358#issuecomment-502325845

Comment: OP asked about auto-quotes too...   to do so just add to the json:
 "autoCloseQuotes": false

Comment: Perfect! And you don't even need to run in a notebook: it can be a simple terminal python (useful when you have multiple kernels in multiple environments which do not all have jupyters).

Answer (score 15):

For JupyterLab visitors there is a "User Preferences" panel of the "Notebook" settings editor into which you paste & save:

```
{
  "codeCellConfig": {
    "autoClosingBrackets": false
  }
}
```

Open with `Ctrl + ,` or via menu: `Settings` → `Advanced Settings Editor` & click "Notebook"

Comment: Sadly this change doesn't seem to survive restarts of AWS SageMaker notebook instances.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply got to ***Settings*** tab and *uncheck* ***Auto Close Brackets*** option to disable auto-complete or check it to enable auto-complete

Answer (score 5):

**Here is my 2 jpgs:**

[step 1] Go to **"Advanced Settings"** under **"Settings"** in menu:

[image: "Advanced Settings" under "Settings"]

[step 2]
Select the **"Notebook"** category, in the **"User Preference"** tab, add text as follows: (just follow the syntax shown in the **"System Defaults"** tab):

```
{
    "codeCellConfig": {
        "autoClosingBrackets": false,
    },   
}
```

[image: add text as follows in the "User Preference"]

FYI:

```
!jupyter --version

jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.3.0
qtconsole        : 5.0.3
ipython          : 7.22.0
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.0.14
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```