# Left key exit insert mode in bash commandline

Tags: bash, readline

I would like to do something like this in bash:

```
bind -m vi-insert '"{" "\C-v{}\e[D"'
```

This works except after autoclosing } and put the cursor in the middle, it also exits the insert mode, which is very annoying.

Comment: I've updated my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11661658/1126841) to address your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given macro assumes Emacs key bindings; after inserting the braces, the escape sequence `\e[D` moves the cursor one cell to the left, positioning it between the braces. In vi mode, the `\e` has the effect of exiting insert mode and going back to command mode. A simple fix is to leave insert mode, then immediately re-enter, which will also reposition the cursor where you want it; no explicit cursor movement is necessary.

```
bind -m vi-insert '"{" "\C-v{}\ei"'
```