# How to move the cursor on the editing line with cl-readline

Tags: terminal, common-lisp, readline

I am trying to learn how to use [`cl-readline`](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-readline/). One thing I want to do is bind the "(" key to a function, which inserts "()" and move the cursor between the two characters. I actually know how to do it with bash's `bind` command:

```
    bind '"(": "\C-q(\C-q)\C-b"'
```

But I have no idea how to do it with `cl-readline`. So far I have tried something like:

```
(defun insert-paren (arg key)
  (declare (ignore arg key))
  (rl:insert-text "()")
  (rl:insert-text (format nil "~C[1D" #\Esc)))

(rl:bind-keyseq "(" #'insert-paren)
```

According to https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html, "\033[1D" is the escape sequence to move the cursor backward.

But it does not work. It will insert the text like below, rather than move the cursor backward:

```
()^[[1D
```

Comment: It's also possible to do it outside of bash with `"(": "\C-v()\e[D"` into ~/.inputrc, it will work for any program that uses readline. Found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486757/autoclose-gnu-readline

Comment: It looks like `cl-readline` is missing the readline functions `rl_backward_char`, `rl_forward_char`.

Comment: I defined them in cl-readline and I'm working on a little example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cl-readline` didn't have the forward and backward char functions, which are defined in readline.

I pushed a commit that adds them (doc update and example usage there will come in the coming days).

Here's an example, adapted from cl-readline-example. We bind a key that will insert text and move the cursor, once we get a readline prompt.

```lisp
(defun insert-and-move (arg key)
  (rl:insert-text "()")
  (rl:backward-char))  ;; edit: the 1 1 arguments are now optional.

(defun run-example ()
  (rl:bind-keyseq "\\C-o" #'insert-and-move)
  (rl:bind-keyseq "(" #'insert-and-move)
  (rl:bind-keyseq "\\C-\(" #'insert-and-move)

  (handler-case
      (progn
        (rl:readline :prompt "my readline > ")

    … )

(run-example)
```

run the example:

```
$ sbcl --script example.lisp
```

now you can use `(` or `C-(` or `C-o` to enter two `( )` and have the cursor in-between.

- https://github.com/vindarel/cl-readline-example/

Comment: I added `rl:forward-word`, `rl:backward-word`, `beginning-of-line`, `end-of-line`, `clear-screen`, `refresh-line`, `clear-display`.

Comment: doc is published: https://vindarel.github.io/cl-readline/#Moving-the-cursor